# CircularProgressIndicator with a different stroke width

Tags: flutter

How can I increase the stroke width of the `CircularProgressIndicator` value?
It should increase the stroke width for the progressed value.

Here's an [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9aCo.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`strokeWidth`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CircularProgressIndicator/strokeWidth.html) property.

```dart
CircularProgressIndicator(strokeWidth: 8);
```

Comment: Hey, i try to achive only a bigger stroke width for the part that indicates how far it has progressed. I don't want to increase the whole stroke size of the widget.